# Regex containing a [:alnum:] POSIX character class did not match string with C#, but online tool evaluates ok

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex

```
(?'Conpany'Company) - (?'Model'Model) - (?'Version'V(?'Major'\d+).(?'Minor'\d+).(?'Bugfix'\d+).(?'Build'\d+)(?'PreRelease'-[[:alnum:]]*)?(?'Meta'\+[[:alnum:]]*)?) - (?'CompileDate'(?'Year'\d{4})(?'Month'\d{2})(?'Day'\d{2}))
```

that should match a SCPI String

```
Company - Model - V1.0.0.1718-RC1 - 20190821
```

If I try the regex with an online tool, everything works fine and the string matches the regex.

Now i'm trying to use that regex with C# to evaluate a command answer and the result is always false

```
    var regex = @"(?'Conpany'Company) - (?'Model'Model) - (?'Version'V(?'Major'\d+).(?'Minor'\d+).(?'Bugfix'\d+).(?'Build'\d+)(?'PreRelease'-[[:alnum:]]*)?(?'Meta'\+[[:alnum:]]*)?)" - (?'CompileDate'(?'Year'\d{4})(?'Month'\d{2})(?'Day'\d{2}))";

    // 
    responce = await rs232Device.SendCommand(query, DefaultTimeout);

    var match  = Regex.Match(responce.Message, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    //
    Assert.That(match.Success, Is.True);
```

I found out that the compile date `- (?'CompileDate'(?'Year'\d{4})(?'Month'\d{2})(?'Day'\d{2}))` from the regex everything is fine.

But I don't know why it doesn't work with the complete regex in C# while https://regex101.com/ could match the string.

Comment: Use .NET compatible testers. POSIX character classes are not supported in .NET regex, and you have `[[:alnum:]]` here, replacing it with `[^\W\p{Pc}]` or `\w` will make it work. Besides, escape literal dots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET regex engine does not support POSIX character classes. You have `[[:alnum:]]` here, replacing it with `\w` (any [**word** char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w)), or `[\p{L}\p{N}]` (any letter or digit) or `[^\W\p{Pc}]` (any word char except the connector punctuation like `_`) will make it work.

See other POSIX character classes *example* mappings (they may fail to work exactly the same but at least similarly):

```
POSIX        .NET             Description
[:alpha:]   \p{L}           Any letters (\p{L} matches only those from the BMP plane)
[:alnum:]   [\p{L}\p{N}]    Any letters or digits
[:digit:]   \p{N} or \d     Any digits (there is also a [:d:] POSIX variation)
[:space:]   \s or \p{Z}     Any whitespace
[:blank:]   [\p{Zs}\t]      Any horizontal whitespace
```

Besides, some extend them to

```
POSIX        .NET             Description
[:ascii:]   [\x00-\x7E]     ASCII character set
[:xdigit:]  [0-9a-fA-F]     Chars that are used to define hex values
```

Besides, you must escape literal dots in the pattern.

Also, always use the Web regex tester that is compatible with the regex engine you plan to use with your pattern.

```
(?'Conpany'Company) - (?'Model'Model) - (?'Version'V(?'Major'\d+)\.(?'Minor'\d+)\.(?'Bugfix'\d+)\.(?'Build'\d+)(?'PreRelease'-\w*)?(?'Meta'\+\w*)?) - (?'CompileDate'(?'Year'\d{4})(?'Month'\d{2})(?'Day'\d{2}))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%27Conpany%27Company%29%20-%20%28%3F%27Model%27Model%29%20-%20%28%3F%27Version%27V%28%3F%27Major%27%5Cd%2B%29%5C.%28%3F%27Minor%27%5Cd%2B%29%5C.%28%3F%27Bugfix%27%5Cd%2B%29%5C.%28%3F%27Build%27%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%27PreRelease%27-%5Cw*%29%3F%28%3F%27Meta%27%5C%2B%5Cw*%29%3F%29%20-%20%28%3F%27CompileDate%27%28%3F%27Year%27%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%28%3F%27Month%27%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%3F%27Day%27%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29&i=Company%20-%20Model%20-%20V1.0.0.1718-RC1%20-%2020190821)

[image]